# How to sum rowcounts

Tags: sql, oracle, select

How would I count the number of rows in three tables and return the sum of the three row counts?

Comment: UNION the three queries and SUM the count values

Answer (score 2):

This will return every table count on your db just add the `WHERE` to filter the ones you want

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_count_rows_all_tables_in_schema.htm

```
select
   table_name,
   to_number(
   extractvalue(
      xmltype(
         dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||table_name))
    ,'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) row_count
from 
   user_tables
order by 
   table_name;
```

Just include this in a `CTE` to get the `SUM`

```
WITH cte AS ( 
    select
       table_name,
       to_number(
       extractvalue(
          xmltype(
             dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||table_name))
        ,'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) row_count
    from 
       user_tables
    WHERE table_name in ('table1', 'table2', 'table3' )
)
SELECT SUM(row_count)
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(rowcount) from
(
select count(*)  as rowcount from tablea a
UNION
select count(*) from tableb b
UNION
select count(*) from tablec c
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of rows of a table is returned as a single row result, you could cross the join the three **results** and sum them with the `+` operator:

```
SELECT     a.cnt + b.cnt + c.cnt
FROM       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table_a) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table_b) b
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table_c) c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(v.cnt) as total_sum
from 
 (select count (*) as cnt from <<table1>>
  union all
  select count (*) as cnt from <<table2>>
  union all
  select count (*) as cnt from <<table3>>) v
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
cnt1 + cnt2 + cnt3
as mycnt
from 
(SELECT COUNT (*) as cnt1 FROM s1.t1),
(SELECT COUNT (*) as cnt2 FROM s1.t2),
(SELECT COUNT (*) as cnt3 FROM s1.t3)
```

Is what I ended up using. Thanks all.